# Visual Studio C++ 2008 Manipulating Bytes?

Tags: byte, filestream, streamwriter

I'm trying to write strictly binary data to files (no encoding). The problem is, when I hex dump the files, I'm noticing rather weird behavior. Using either one of the below methods to construct a file results in the same behavior. I even used the `System::Text::Encoding::Default` to test as well for the streams.

```
StreamWriter^ binWriter = gcnew StreamWriter(gcnew FileStream("test.bin",FileMode::Create));

(Also used this method)
FileStream^ tempBin = gcnew FileStream("test.bin",FileMode::Create);
BinaryWriter^ binWriter = gcnew BinaryWriter(tempBin);


binWriter->Write(0x80);
binWriter->Write(0x81);
.
.
binWriter->Write(0x8F);
binWriter->Write(0x90);
binWriter->Write(0x91);
.
.
binWriter->Write(0x9F);
```

Writing that sequence of bytes, I noticed the only bytes that *weren't* converted to `0x3F` in the hex dump were `0x81`,`0x8D`,`0x90`,`0x9D`, ... and I have no idea why.

I also tried making character arrays, and a similar situation happens. i.e.,

```
array<wchar_t,1>^ OT_Random_Delta_Limits = {0x00,0x00,0x03,0x79,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x88};
binWriter->Write(OT_Random_Delta_Limits);
```

`0x88` would be written as `0x3F`.

Comment: Also, I left out the fact that ONLY the 0x8 and 0x9 sequence of bytes seem to affected. 0xF9 or 0xC3, for example, write like they are supposed to. 0x3F is ASCII for the ? if anyone was interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick to binary files then **don't use `StreamWriter`**. Just use a `FileStream` and `Write`/`WriteByte`. StreamWriters (and TextWriters in generally) are expressly designed for *text*. Whether you want an encoding or not, one will be applied - because when you're calling `StreamWriter.Write`, that's writing a `char`, not a `byte`.

Don't create arrays of `wchar_t` values either - again, those are for *characters*, i.e. text.

`BinaryWriter.Write` should have worked for you unless it was promoting the values to `char` in which case you'd have exactly the same problem.

By the way, without specifying *any* encoding, I'd expect you to get non-0x3F values, but instead the bytes representing the UTF-8 encoded values for those characters.

When you specified `Encoding.Default`, you'd have seen 0x3F for any Unicode values not in that encoding.

Anyway, the basic lesson is to stick to `Stream` when you want to deal with binary data rather than text.

EDIT: Okay, it would be something like:

```
public static void ConvertHex(TextReader input, Stream output)
{
    while (true)
    {
        int firstNybble = input.Read();
        if (firstNybble == -1)
        {
            return;
        }
        int secondNybble = input.Read();
        if (secondNybble == -1)
        {
            throw new IOException("Reader finished half way through a byte");
        }
        int value = (ParseNybble(firstNybble) << 4) + ParseNybble(secondNybble);
        output.WriteByte((byte) value);
    }
}

// value would actually be a char, but as we've got an int in the above code,
// it just makes things a bit easier
private static int ParseNybble(int value)
{
    if (value >= '0' && value <= '9') return value - '0';
    if (value >= 'A' && value <= 'F') return value - 'A' + 10;
    if (value >= 'a' && value <= 'f') return value - 'a' + 10;
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid nybble: " + (char) value);
}
```

This is very inefficient in terms of buffering etc, but should get you started.

Comment: Part of the issue, though, is I'm reading a large file of text and extracting the bytes as I need. The use of StreamReader::ReadToEnd() is really, really handy.

Comment: If you're reading a large file of text then you're *not* dealing with bytes, you're dealing with *text*. You need to keep them very clearly separate in your head.

Comment: Yeah.. The problem with doing that is, I'm having issues with the compiler understanding what I'm trying to do. What I *really* want to do is parse the ASCII text and concatenate 2 consecutive characters to form a "byte", then write it's binary form, not it's ASCII equivalent. For example, I'll concatenate the strings "1" and "2", but when I convert and write as a byte, it'll write 0x0C instead of 0x12. The Convert::ToByte and WriteByte() methods don't like that, but I see no other way to do that.  I can't seem to force the compiler to play by my rules.

Comment: Sorry, are you *trying* to write 0x12 or 0x0C? Are you basically trying to convert hex into binary? If so, I can write C# code to do that and let you figure out how to port it to C++ :)

Comment: I'm trying to write 0x12 *not* 0x0C. I suppose you could say I'm trying to convert hex to binary. In a nutshell, I'm parsing in hex strings from a file, concatenating consecutive characters, and transforming that to a byte. So when I read in "12", I don't want to write back "0x31 0x32" or "0x0C", I want the concatenated byte representation of "12"... 0x12. Sorry if my explaination is crappy.

Comment: That does indeed sound like just decoding a text file of hex into a binary file. I suggest you have a method which takes a TextReader (input) and a Stream (output). Let me know if you want me to write the method for you in C#. Oh, and will there be line breaks?

Comment: Yeah, if you'd like to write up some pseudocode that'd be awesome... Though the logic isn't slipping me, I've tried a lot of different methods, but I suppose they're technically incorrect. No line breaks, straight up raw and dirty binary.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, you've been helpful beyond all my expectations. I might have to join this community!

Comment: Update: I adjusted two segments of Tony's code posted above, which may or may have not been oversights on his part, but....

1) The "ParseNybble" returns the var "value", but is defined with no return type. I changed to int and it appears to work as intended.

2) For the line
*if (value >= 'f' && value <= 'f') return value - 'a' + 10;*
I changed the first 'f' to 'a', otherwise the code won't handle lower-case ASCII characters correctly, and will return an Invalid Nybble exception.

Answer (score 0):

0x3F is commonly known as the ASCII character '?'; the characters that are mapping to it are control characters with no printable representation.  As Jon points out, use a binary stream rather than a text-oriented output mechanism for raw binary data.

EDIT -- actually your results look like the inverse of what I would expect.  In the default [code page 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), the non-printable characters (i.e. ones likely to map to '?') in that range are 0x81, 0x8D, 0x8F, 0x90 and 0x9D

Answer (score 0):

A `BinaryWriter()` class initialized with a stream will use a default encoding of UTF8 for any chars or strings that are written. I'm guessing that the

```
binWriter->Write(0x80);
binWriter->Write(0x81);
.
.
binWriter->Write(0x8F);
binWriter->Write(0x90);
binWriter->Write(0x91);
```

calls are binding to the `Write( char)` overload so they're going through the character encoder.  I'm not very familiar with C++/CLI, but it seems to me that these calls should be binding to `Write(Int32)`, which shouldn't have this problem (maybe your code is really calling `Write()` with a `char` variable that's set to the values in your example. That would account for this behavior).